# How to syncronize 4 different processes with Mutex or EventWaitHandler

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I have found several ways of synchronizing 2 different processes using a named Mutex or other locks available in .Net but I have not found how to do it with more than 2 processes.

I need to synch 4 different processes accessing to a shared resource. I've tried with:

```
        bool createdNew;
        using (EventWaitHandle eventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, MutexName, out createdNew))
        {
            if (!createdNew)
            {
                eventWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            }

 ... Critical section

            eventWaitHandle.Set();
        }
```

But only works with 2 processes, when the handle is set all the waiting processes start at the same time.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: Only one of the 4 processes should be able to enter the critical section at any given time

Comment: You need to assign a master process, one that owns the mutexes.  And takes care of all the other nasty little details, like one of these processes terminating unexpectedly.  Very hard to recover from so it needs to kill everybody else as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mutex for that still:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    bool owned;
    // first process will achieve ownership here, when creating
    var mutex = new Mutex(true, "mymutex", out owned);
    try {
        if (!owned) {
            // other processes will wait here, but only one will be released at a time
            owned = mutex.WaitOne();
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Using the mutex on process {Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    finally {
        if (owned)
            // if we own mutex - release to allow next processes to come in.
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Of course you may want to wrap that into handy IDisposable class. Don't forget to set proper timeout in `WaitOne`.

Comment: Are you sure? Whit the EventWaitHandle all the waiting processes get released when the event gets set.

Comment: Yes I tested the code above with 4 processes, and they enter crtitical section one by one. It's important to properly use mutex (note how owned variable is used) to achieve correct result.